# Unity Raycast gives same result

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = new Ray(character.cam.transform.position, character.cam.lookDir);
    if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
        Debug.Log(hit.transform.position);
    }
```

this gives the same answer (0, -1.5, 0) no matter if I move the camera or player.  The lookDIr is sound and the position is obviously sound.  When i put the ray direction to straight down, it works, but not with the lookDir.

Comment: You could first try to recreate the Ray that you would like so see (Read this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html))

With this you can draw a ray and see it in the inspector to see what you're doing.

`Debug.DrawRay(character.cam.transform.position, character.cam.lookDir, Color.green);`

EDIT:
I couldn't find cam.lookDir in the ScriptReference, are you sure that that exists?

Comment: i was giving the center of the floor, which is (0, -1.5 0).   I just had to use RaycastHit.point

Answer (score 0):

It is worth paying attention to the fact that `hit.transform` return transform of other object.

> hitInfo - If true is returned, hitInfo will contain more information about where the collider was hit. (See Also: RaycastHit).

(from [Physics.Raycast description](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html))

In your case looks like you ray-casting same object every time.